# I want to get last inserted id in csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I want to get last insert id in csv file using php. I want to import csv in MS-Access database using php.

Currently my code is working perfectly, the only concern about when i try to upload in second time, then i insert data after last inserted id.

[image]

This is id column of my csv file.

and this is code.

```
if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size']) && $_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0){
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 


echo $type = $data[31];
$row = 0;
$last_row = array_pop($data[]);
//echo $last_data = str_getcsv($last_row);
//loop through the csv file and insert into database 
do { 

    //$values = implode(",",$data);

    if ($row == 0) {//skip first row (headers)
        $row++;
    } else {


        $type = $data[31];
        if($type == 'industrial'){
            if ($data[0]) { 

                $sql1_ind = "INSERT INTO colours(COLNO, COLNAME, MAKER, SOURCE, BASE, undercoat, colourcode, application) VALUES 
                    ( 
                        '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[5])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[6])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[7])."'
                    )"; 

                if($database_ind->query($sql1_ind)) {
                    echo 'Data is imported successfully in Industrial Database.';
                    echo '<br>';
                }   else    {
                    $db_err = $database_ind->errorInfo();
                }
                for($i=0;$i<6;$i=$i+1){
                    $colno = $data[0];

                    $tint_base_form = $data[4];

                    $ingred_form  = $data[8+3*$i];

                    $y = $data[9+3*$i];

                    $unit = $data[10+3*$i];

                    if($ingred_form!=''){

                        $qty = $y*2 + $unit;
                        $seq = 1+$i;
                        $sql2_ind = "INSERT INTO colour_details(colno, seq, tintcode, qty) VALUES('".$colno."', '".$seq."', '".$tint_base_form."', '".$qty."')";
                        $result_sql2_ind = $database_ind->query($sql2_ind);
                        if($database_ind->query($sql2_ind)) {
                            echo 'Data is inserted successfully in colour details table. ';
                            echo '<br>';
                        }   else    {
                            $db_err = $database_ind->errorInfo();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        } else {
            if ($data[0]) { 

                $sql1_ind = "INSERT INTO colours(COLNO, COLNAME, MAKER, SOURCE, BASE, undercoat, colourcode, application) VALUES 
                    ( 
                        '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[5])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[6])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[7])."'
                    )"; 

                if($database_deco->query($sql1_ind)) {
                    echo 'Data is imported successfully in Decorative Database.';
                    echo '<br>';
                }   else    {
                    $db_err = $database_deco->errorInfo();
                }

                for($i=0;$i<6;$i=$i+1){
                    $colno = $data[0];

                    $tint_base_form = $data[4];

                    $ingred_form  = $data[8+3*$i];

                    $y = $data[9+3*$i];

                    $unit = $data[10+3*$i];

                    if($ingred_form!=''){

                        $qty = $y*2 + $unit;
                        $seq = 1+$i;
                        $sql2_ind = "INSERT INTO colour_details(colno, seq, tintcode, qty) VALUES('".$colno."', '".$seq."', '".$tint_base_form."', '".$qty."')";
                        $result_sql2_ind = $database_deco->query($sql2_ind);
                        if($database_deco->query($sql2_ind)) {
                            echo 'Data is inserted successfully in colour details table. ';
                            echo '<br>';
                        }   else    {
                            $db_err = $database_deco->errorInfo();
                            //echo 'Error : ('. $db_err[2] .')';
                            //echo 'Error : ('. $db_err[0] .') -- ' . $db_err[2];
                            //echo 'ERROR';
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    } 
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

please give me some suggestions.

Comment: *the only concern about when i try to upload in second time, then i insert data after last inserted id* - I don't really understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: _Currently my code is working perfectly_ ??? Really? Then you have not tested it! You are using a `do while` loop so therefore you dont actually read the csv file until after you have processed **non-existing** data in the first pass of your loop. So obviously you are running with `errors` turned off. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply GolezTrol,

I want insert data after last inserted id, when i want to upload csv in second time.

So i want to get Last inserted id from CSV file.

Comment: How can i get last inserted id in csv file using php?